# How to stretch Containers inside Row to maximum available height?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a Row widget, which has many containers with different heights depending on their content. I want to have an equal height of them all. How can I achieve this without hardcoding their values?

This is something I have.
[image]

But I want the first card to take the height of the row automatically. So that both cards would be of the same height. How can I achieve this?

This is the code for Card Container:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final statusMap = statusOptionView();
    return Container(
      width: 200,
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                left: 20.0, right: 20.0, top: 20.0, bottom: 50.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
              color: Color(0xFFF97F8B),
            ),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(
                      Icons.access_time,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(width: 4.0),
                    Text(
                      event.startTime,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20.0,
                ),
                Text(
                  event.title,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  maxLines: 2,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20.0,
                ),
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(
                      Icons.location_on,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 4.0,
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Text(
                        event.venue,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        maxLines: 1,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            bottom: 0.0,
            right: 0.0,
            left: 0.0,
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () => Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) => EventDetailsScreen(event: event, status: status))),
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.purple,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(
                      statusMap['icon'],
                      color: Colors.white,
                      size: 16.0,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 10.0,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      statusMap['value'],
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

While it is wrapped inside a Row widget, just like this:

```
Row(
  children: <Widget>[...events.map((event) => EventCard(event: event)).toList()],
)
```

Comment: provide your code.

Comment: code is  provided.

Comment: Try crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch inside the Row widget

Comment: @ArshShaikh It failed with the error: BoxConstraints forces an infinite height.

Comment: Then wrap your Row with Expanded widget

Comment: Yup Wrap the row in Expanded or if you have a fixed height in mind, wrap the row with a container and give the container that height.

Comment: @ArshShaikh same error. This is not due to the row itself. Row is working correctly, but it is due to Event Card which is not adjusting to the height of Row. And I don't want to give it a fixed height. :(

Comment: I have used provided height of double.infinity to the Event Card Container but it is having same error..

Answer (score 10):

Use `IntrinsicHeight` as parent of `Row` that contains `Card`

Comment: This should be the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CrossAxisAlignment.stretch` to make all children of a Row/Column use the same height/width.

```dart
  /// Require the children to fill the cross axis.  
  ///  
  /// This causes the constraints passed to the children to be tight in the  
  /// cross axis.  
  stretch,
```

Check out https://codepen.io/kuhnroyal/pen/wvGormg

Comment: I have tried it, but getting error, while using stretch. Can you rewrite your code please, so that I can understand it?

Comment: There is nothing to rewrite, the sample is very basic. If you don't understand it, you should read some tutorials on how to use columns and rows. And if you get an error then you are doing something different, you can see in the example that it does what you want. What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, **row is a child of column** and column gives full available height to its children so row as a child of the column, take full available height so to tell column that only give required height to its children try to give **`MainAxisSize.min`** property to Column. I am not sure it works or not but you can try.

Comment: No. this doesn't help me either. Can you try rewrite your code and post it in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Row(
mainAxisAlignment : MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
.....)

or try wrapping every widget with expanded.

Hoping that it works

Comment: Nope. Still not working. Can you write your full code?

Comment: `Expanded` expands its child in the main axis direction.  The question is asking about the cross axis direction.